# How to get the Primary Key value after Select using Stored Procedure?

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures, jdbc

How can I get the value of the existing Primary Key ID in my data? I tried to select a data but it's not getting the value in my current table.
When I try search a existing record. It prints to the textfields. Also when I search a non existing record it still prints to the textfields. Did I missed something?

**Non Existing Record**

[image]

**TABLE**

```
CREATE TABLE allsections_list
(
 SECTION_ID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
 SECTION_NAME INT VARCHAR(50)
)
```

**STORED PROCEDURE**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getSECTION_NAME (IN SECTION_NAME VARCHAR(50))
SELECT SECTION_NAME FROM allsections_list
```

**DATA**

[image]

**CODE**

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String searchSection = Section_SearchSection_Textfield.getText();
    String searchSection_Name = Section_SectionName_TextField.getText();
    int sectionId = 0;
    if (searchSection.isEmpty())
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please fill up this fields");
    }
    else 
        try (Connection myConn = DBUtil.connect())
        {   
            try (CallableStatement myFirstCs = myConn.prepareCall("{call getSECTION_NAME(?)}"))
            {
                myFirstCs.setString(1, searchSection);//Get value of Section_SearchSection_Textfield

                myFirstCs.executeQuery();

            try (ResultSet myRs = myFirstCs.executeQuery())
            {
                int resultsCounter = 0;
                while (myRs.next())
                {
                    String getSection_Name = myRs.getString(1);
                    sectionID = myRs.getInt("SECTION_ID");

                    Section_SectionName_TextField.setText(getSection_Name);//Set the value of text
                    Section_SectionName_TextField.setEnabled(true);//Set to enable

                    System.out.print(sectionID);
                    resultsCounter++;

                }//end of while
                }//end of resultset
            }//end of callablestatement
        }//end of connection
        catch (SQLException e) 
        {
            DBUtil.processException(e);
        }  
}
```

Any help or tips will appreciate! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You only have an IN parameter in your procedure definition. You might use an OUT parameter, set it in the procedure and SELECT it after execution to get the result, like here: [mysql manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/call.html)

in the first example.